# How to plot $x^2+y^2 = 4$ and $z=2$ in 3-dimensional space in Latex

Tags: pgfplots, plot, tikz-3dplot

I'm trying to plot $x^2+y^2 = 4$ and $z=2$ in 3-dimensional space with axes labels.

I came across pgfplot and tikz-3dplot but I could not do it.

Comment: Both in Tikz-3dplot and pgfplots this is just a circle of radius 2 in the xy plane at z=2. In tikz-3dplot you can use the key “canvas is currently plane at z=2” for that. If you need explicit examples, please let me know.

Comment: I am guessing the OP means a cylinder and a plane, and perhaps their intersections, simultaneously on a 3d system.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a circle of radius 2 in the xy plane at `z=2`. You can draw this circle both with `tikz-3dplot` and `pgfplots`. Here is a `tikz-3dplot` variant.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{110}{70} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=2]
  \draw (0,0) circle[radius=2cm];
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How this circle really is going to look depends on the view angles, which are specified by `\tdplotsetmaincoords{110}{70}` in the above example. You may only appreciate `z=2` really after adding other stuff at different `z` position,